# Importing Bootstrap in project folder when I add @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; then the live server creates an error and stops

Tags: import, sass, bootstrap-5

I went onto bootstrap.com and I'm following along an article from getting started. I added everything correctly inside my webpack.config.js and also in my package.json (I will post all the pictures of what I have done) and in my index.html. I didn't skip any steps or change anything. I even used all the names for the files that they suggested just to make sure I also started out completely fresh using my Git bash.

As soon as I got to importing bootstrap by adding @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; into my styles.scss then I ran into issues and got an error on the browser which I will also add a picture of the error and what it looks like before the error. What could I change to fix this?

I tried adding the imports that were suggested if you just want to add certain features of Bootstrap to your project and I also followed the link that the error gave me and read that article but wasn't really sure if any of it was useful or not. Plus not knowing that much like myself makes it difficult to understand exactly everything they are describing. All I know for sure is when I delete `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` from my styles.scss that everything works again. I also posted the last part of the instructions for extra information of what I did.

Now, I decided to try something else and use `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` instead because it was stating that the relative path didn't exist. And then I got another error but could see that it did work in the background so I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm stumped.

This is the line that I added that caused the error:

[image: This is the line that I added that caused the error]

This is my package.json:

[image: This is my package.json]

This is my index.html:

[image: This is my index.html]

This is my main.js:

[image: This is my main.js]

This is the error that popped up:

[image: This is the error that popped up]

This is what it looked like before the error:

[image: This is what it looked like before the error]

This is the second error I got after adding node_modules to the import line:

[image: This is the second error I got after adding node_modules to the import line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just in case anyone has the same issues as me. Go ahead and check your spelling on everything, thats not what my issue was but thats usually what my issue is. My issue on this was the @ symbol in the first snapshot i uploaded. Took out the @ symbol and it worked.